# Android Studio view binding import incorrect path

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewbinding

Android Studio is adamant to import R and DataBinding from a path containing a dash.

[image]

This causes compilation errors, obviously, since you should not have dashes in module names. The problem is that I have looked everywhere for where I might have declared this module incorrectly, but I can can only find the correct path of `corporateactions`.

The other imports from this module are fine:
[image]

I ctrl+f the entire module looking for a `corporate-actions` declaration, but I cannot find any. Module is named `corporate-actions`, but I fail to see that it would be a problem since multiple module names contain dashes.

I even checked the autogenerated viewbinding class, but it seems to be importing the correct path. I am scratching my head here. What did I mess up?

It only seems to affect layout imports.

Comment: Try removing the dash from the module name.

Answer (score 1):

So after rigorously checking every single possibility that I might have declared anything incorrectly, I had a coworker test the branch on his machine and sure enough, no wonky imports.

So somehow it had cached the incorrect import path locally on my machine, which `clean` did not solve. **After invalidating the cache and restarting** Android Studio it now works as intended.

Happy little bug that costed me around 2 hours. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Always worth trying an **invalidate cache and restart** if a problem doesn't make any sense, or clearing gradle caches and then invalidating/restarting.